# "Cheatin’ uh?" error message on multple theme directories

Tags: theme-development, themes

In my `wp-config.php` I've added another theme directory; `register_theme_directory( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '\..\themes' );`. I'm not sure if this is the correct place to add it.

When I then try to preview my theme, I just get the error message `Cheatin’ uh?`.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is currently broken in WordPress. You can only add theme directories in the `wp-content` directory.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. You'll have to post it as an answer if you want me to accept it :)

Comment: I have a workaround for that, but that has to wait until this evening if you can wait that long. :)

Comment: @toscho When you have the time, I would like to try the workaround :) But, it's not something critical, so just when you have the time to post it.

Comment: Same exact problem with me, except I get a blank page instead of a "cheatin'" message. Is wp-config too early a stage to call this function?

Answer (score -2):

Make sure that you're logged in as admin

1. Goto Settings
2. General Settings
3. Make sure that your site URL is "http://yoursitehere.com"

If you have previously changed that it could cause you problems all across the board.